# Web Fonts (WOFF) are only blurry in Firefox v32.0 (Current) with ClearType Disabled

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

I see this question has been asked in different ways but perhaps not in such a direct manner.  I'm on a fresh load of Windows 8.1 with a default setting of ClearType Disabled.  Web Fonts render perfectly fine in all browsers except for Firefox.  In Firefox, they appear blurred or pixelated.  When I enable ClearType they suddenly are fine in Firefox.  Oddly if I then disable ClearType and logout and then login, they are still fine.  I see that Google Chrome previously had a similar issue but understand they fixed the issue in Chrome.  Is this an issue that needs to be addressed by Firefox?  Are antialias properties going to be advanced in CSS to possibly force fonts to render properly?

Comment: Fonts are stored locally on the same domain as the website.

Comment: try placing TTF/OTF in the first line, then EOT, then WOFF and see if that solves your issue

Comment: I tried putting src TTF first and then WOFF second but it made no difference.  Is OTF and EOT needed?

Comment: TTF and OTF are basically the same, some fonts are TTF and some OTF, hence why I added them as the same thing. EOT tends to work better with IE, anyways, my suggestion was to see if loading order would prevent this since what you're facing is DirectDraw rendering issues. If that didn't solve the issue, really don't know what to tell you, but this is very interesting so will try some testing on my side and see if I can find out

Answer (score 0):

Does the problem reproduce with hardware acceleration disabled?

If it does not, you are seeing this long standing issue[1](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=719410) - DirectWrite font rendering with ClearType disabled sometimes does not work correctly when using hardware accelerated drawing. As far as I know there are no font-rendering related changes in Firefox 32 (you didn't clarify if this is a regression versus Firefox 31 or you only just noticed this problem), but there are changes that extend the use of hardware-accelerated drawing.

Note that there is a difference between disabling font smoothing and disabling ClearType. If it works correctly in Chrome, that might be the issue, because Chrome has the directly opposite bug such as not respecting the settings[2](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=399504) correctly[3](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=319429).

Answer (score -1):

v32 appears to have botched font rendering - with v31, WOFF and other font types render perfectly, whereas in 32 they are missing portions of the glyphs.

Comment: Is there a bulletin somewhere that would document that?